# NFS share inside a NFS or Samba share cannot be accessed

Tags: samba, nfs, sles

I have this MCVE under SLES 11 SP2:

1) Server `10.10.50.199` has the directory `/foo/`. Inside `/foo` there is a directory `bar/` which is used in `/etc/fstab` : `10.10.50.200:/nfs_folder /foo/bar`

2) Server `10.10.50.199` has an NFS export of `/foo` which means that `/foo/bar` is *included* in this export.

And now something very strange happens: When I access the NFS share `10.10.50.199:/foo` on a Windows Server 2012 R2 then the `/foo/bar/` directory is empty even `/foo/bar/` has lot of entries.

When I access the NFS share `10.10.50.200:/nfs_folder` directly on the Windows Server 2012 R2 then I can see its content.

The same happens when `/foo`  is a Samba share which includes the `10.10.50.200:/nfs_folder` NFS share.

Any write operation into this embedded NFS share is denied but when I write directly into the `10.10.50.200:/nfs_folder` share then it works.

Under Samba I am using the `hide files` directive to hide the `bar/`  directory and prevent any problems. But under NFS I cannot exclude this directory.

Any idea what is going on? Is it forbidden to embed NFS shares?